# Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'. when using Date object

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

I have component that gets data from a class/model (projInfo), including a date object. 
I need to use the different parts of the date (day/month/year) formatted such that i need to break them up and put them in an array.

I can't seem to parse the Date object into a string[] type. Here's what I have:

```
  public _startDate = this.projInfo.startdato; //.toString();

  @Input()
  set startDate(startDate: string) {
    // remove commas then split into array
    const d: string = this.startDateFormat.replace(',', '');
    this._startDate = d.split(' ');
  }
```

"this._startDate" on last line provides and error  `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'`.
How do I solve this? It's hard to search for answers because I think the error is too broad.

Comment: Do you want `_startDate` to be a string or an array of strings?

Comment: what is startDateFormat ?

Comment: _startDate is a string because this.projInfo.startDato is a string. split return an array, so you can not equale _startDate to an array (well really you can define public _startDate:string|string[]=this.projInfo.startdato, but I think you don't want do this)

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize a class variable and assign it a value like

```
public _startDate = this.projInfo.startdato;
```

and this.projInfo.startdato has the type string, the typescript compiler will assume the type of _startDate to be a string as well.
Since the split method of a string: String.prototype.split() will return an array the compiler complains.

You have to decide which type your _startDate variable should be. I don't know what this.projInfo.startdato is so i can not give you any solution for that.

Generally you could initialize your variable with a type like:

```
public _startDate: Array<string> = [this.projInfo.startdato];
```

And typecasting in typescript would work like

```
this._startDate = <string> d.split(' '); // I guess this still won't work in this case
```